# Dual Boot - Machine restarts before installing

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to create a dual boot. I tried installing ubuntu from a pen drive with Install alongside windows option. After I press install, the system just restarts with windows. I used Universal-USB-Installer for the pendrive. I use windows 7, hp Pavillion dv6. The iso file is not corrupt; I checked the md5sum. Also, I have already manually created a partition from windows. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The causes for such a thing can be many, corrupted image, corrupted writing of the image on the pen drive or a corrupted pen drive.

Make sure you run the universal installer as administrator on windows.
Or you can also try `unetbootin` to create the bootable pen drive, but you will also need to run it as administrator.

Comment: I tried it with unetbootin as well. The exact same thing happens. Its a new pen drive, so I am not sure if it ll be corrupt. The image is not corrupt as I checked the msd5 checksum. Is it a good idea to install it using wubi that comes with the iso image?

Comment: It will work to install using wubi, will be a bit slower though, if your installing it to check stuff and see if you can manage using it to see if you can convert to it, this will be a good idea to use wubi, if you are already good with ubuntu and want to make the best out of it, burn the image into a DVD and do a regular install, it will perform better, when i used to do installs from pen drives some just did not work, on another pen drive with the same iso it did, would be a good idea to try another pen drive if you have one.